# Оборот "Через час" (значение)

Tags: лексика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли употреблять оборот "через час" в значении следующего часа? Предположим, сейчас 9:00, а речь идет о 10:00.

Answer (score 1):

***Через час*** значит ***по прошествии часа,*** то есть в момент, когда будет *та же минута следующего часа.* В Вашем примере так и получается.

Comment: А как тогда сообщить об 11?

Comment: Через два часа. Тут по-другому, чем с остановками, где "через одну" значит "на второй по счёту".